# Cannot use both covariance and contravariance on interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I’m having some problems with interfaces and co/contravariance and I’m having some problems. Imagine a structure like below (excuse any obvious mistakes, I’m in mobile at the moment)

```
public interface IDelimitedFileReader<T>
{
      IEnumerable<T> Read(string file);
}

public interface IMapper<T> where T : IManifestItem
{
      MappedRecord Map(IEnumerable<T> items);
}

public interface IProfile<T> where T : IManifestItem
{
      IDelimitedFileReader<T> Reader { get; }

      IMapper<T> Mapper { get; }
}

public class ProfileImpl : IProfile<ManifestItemImpl>
{
           IDelimitedFileReader<ManifestItemImpl> Reader => new DelimitedFileReaderImpl<ManifestItemImpl>();

      IMapper<ManifestItemImpl> Mapper => new MapperImpl<ManifestItemImpl>();
}

public static class ProfileRetriever
{
     public static IProfile<IManifestItem> GetProfile()
     {
             return new ProfileImpl();
     }
}
```

However my GetProfile method complains that the return types do not match. I believe this is because the IProfile interface needs to be covariant AND contravariant - if I remove the Mapper property on the interface and implementation, and change T to be ‘in’ in IProfile, it works. If I remove Reader, it works if I make T to ‘out’. I need to do both but obviously can’t!

Am I being really stupid or is what I want impossible? Thanks!

Comment: You can't do this, that's correct. However, why do you want to do it? an IAbstract&lt;ConcreteImpl&gt; doesn't seem particularly useful.

Comment: Thanks both, I essentially need to be able to have multiple implementations of IManifestItem, in which can be pass to the DelimitedFileReader and the Mapper, and I thought wrapping up it in a class made sense. Certainly open to any suggestions

Comment: To better describe it, we want a CSV import and mapping procedure that can have different models/mapping’s for different customers. So a CSV will be read to the customers model (MappingItemImpl), then mapped to the generic MappedRecord model using its own class. Hope this conveys what I need from this!

Answer (score 0):

`T` is contravariant in `IMapper` but covariant in `IProfile` and `IDelimitedFileReader`. The definition of something covariant and contravariant is *invariant*, which means that T doesn't allow any type variance; similar to IList. Your current set up will not work.

The issue should be made clear if you declare the desired variance in all interfaces (as you should do, otherwise you'll get cryptic error messages because the compiler can't do any better):

```
interface IDelimitedFileReader<out T> { /*...*/ }
interface IMapper<in T> { /*...*/ }
interface IProfile<out T> { /*...*/ } //at first glance it looks covariant
```

If you try to compile this, the compiler will give you a precise error of whats wrong.

If you declare `T` invariant in `IProfile`: `interface IProfile<T> { //... }` then the error will go away and the code should compile but your stuck with an invariant interface.

Comment: The definition of something convariant and contravariant is *bivariant*. The closest C# has to that is how an `IEnumerable<int>` can be explicitly cast to an `IEnumerable<uint>` and will even work in the sole case of the `IEnumerable<int>` being an `int[]`, and vice-versa. This is generally more a source of trouble than it is useful, but a side effect of the very different covariance that happens with arrays which was more useful prior to generics. It would not be useful with interface variance as no reference types would have bivariant conversions.